# linkedin-j not returning public profile url

Tags: android, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I'm integrating the linkedin-j library with my Android app. I have successfully setup OAuth, and I'm able to retrieve the user's profile:

```
LinkedInApiClient linkedinApiClient = getLinkedinApiClient(accessToken);
Person profile = linkedinApiClient.getProfileForCurrentUser();
```

I'm able to get the user's first name from the API:

```
String firstName = profile.getFirstName();
```

But if I try to get the user's public profile url, I only get null:

```
String profileUrl = profile.getPublicProfileUrl();
```

Why doesn't getPublicProfileUrl work? Is this a known issue of the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add the profile url to the list of fields requested:

```
Set<ProfileField> fields = new HashSet<ProfileField>();
fields.add(ProfileField.PUBLIC_PROFILE_URL);
linkedinApiClient.getProfileForCurrentUser(fields);
```